# Vue.js - how to send send GET request with id as path params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I want to send GET request to my backend app and pass ID as a query params. The path I want to use is - `GET    /api/v1/imports/products_batches/:id`. Here is my code:

`imports.js`

```
const fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest = (token, id) => {
  return axios
    .get(`/api/v1/imports/products_batches`, {
      params: { id: id },
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.data['result']
    })
};
```

`sync_products.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        @click="syncProducts"
      >
        Sync
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import {
  fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest,
} from '../../api/imports'

export default {
  name: 'BackboneSyncProducts',
  data() {
    return {
      fetchedProductSyncResult: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async syncProducts() {
      let confirmationText = `Do you want to ${this.productsToSyncAmount} sync products?`

      if (this.productsToSyncAmount === 0) {
        ModalController.showToast('', 'Type product codes for sync first, please!', 'warning')
      }
      else if (await ModalController.showConfirmation('Confirmation', confirmationText)) {
        try {
          ModalController.showLoader()
          await fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest(this, '43').then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            this.fetchedProductSyncResult = data
          })
          // await createApparelMagicProductsRequest(this, this.styleCodes).then(data => {
            // this.loadId = data['id']
          // })
          const successMessage = `${this.productsToSyncAmount} products have been queued for sync`
          await ModalController.showToast('', successMessage)
        } catch (data) {
          const errorMessage = `Error occurred during queueing products to sync - `
          ModalController.showToast('', errorMessage + data?.message, 'error')
        } finally {
          this.styleCodes = []
          ModalController.hideLoader()
        }
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

As you see, I've hardcoded `id=43` and added `console.log` here:

```
          await fetchSyncedProductsResultRequest(this, '43').then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            this.fetchedProductSyncResult = data
          })
```

and it returns me `undefined`.

I don't know, am I sending the query params not correctly or am I have a typo somewhere? How to send this request correctly ?

Comment: Looking at your axios code, it is fine, I would possible console log `response.data` coming back from the endpoint and seeing what data is being returned to you from the endpoint or `req.query.id` in your server code to ensure it's being passed to your server.

Comment: @Win but is it the right path declaration? EOD I want to hit endpoint `/api/v1/imports/products_batches/43`

Comment: If you bothered to do any debugging (checking the network tab in dev tools), you would notice that the id gets added as "?id=43" to the URL. How do you even expect axios to know, that you want the id appended to the end of the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your

```
axios
    .get(`/api/v1/imports/products_batches`, ...
```

with

```
axios
    .get(`/api/v1/imports/products_batches/${id}`, ...
```

Comment: You were 2 minutes faster than me so I'll mark your answer as correct ;)